# Download PDF with chrome plugin in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pdf

I'm trying to extract a PDF from [this site](http://ecm.cityofchicago.org/eSMARTContracts/service/DPSWebDocumentViewer?sid=ESMART&id=%7BE1274424-4553-4D63-8E65-2EFFDA7E4E59%7D) that uses the native Google Chrome pdf viewer tool to open the pdf in the first place, it's content type is `/application/pdf`. The issue is that the site URLs that I get aren't actually links to the PDF but rather to a `.zul` site where the js will load the pdf, or fetch it.

Here's my download code below:

```
def download_pdf(url, idx, save_dir):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
        "download.default_directory" : save_dir}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
```

The problem that Im encountering with the above code is that I get the following readout from `driver.source_page`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
        <title>Document Viewer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/eSMARTContracts/zkau/web/9776a7f0/zul/css/zk.wcs;jsessionid=088DC94ECA6804AF717A0E997E4F1444.node1"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/eSMARTContracts/zkau/web/9776a7f0/js/zk.wpd;jsessionid=088DC94ECA6804AF717A0E997E4F1444.node1" charset="UTF-8">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/eSMARTContracts/zkau/web/9776a7f0/js/zul.lang.wpd;jsessionid=088DC94ECA6804AF717A0E997E4F1444.node1" charset="UTF-8">
        </script>
        <!-- ZK 6.0.2 EE 2012072410 -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="j4AP_" class="z-temp"></div>
        <script class="z-runonce" type="text/javascript">zk.pi=1;zkmx(
        [0,'j4AP_',{dt:'z_2m1',cu:'/eSMARTContracts;jsessionid=088DC94ECA6804AF717A0E997E4F1444.node1',uu:'/eSMARTContracts/zkau;jsessionid=088DC94ECA6804AF717A0E997E4F1444.node1',ru:'/service/dpsweb/ViewDPSWeb.zul'},[
        ['zul.wnd.Window','j4AP0',{$$onSize:false,$$onMaximize:false,$$onOpen:false,$$onMinimize:false,$$onZIndex:false,$onClose:true,$$onMove:false,width:'100%',height:'100%',prolog:'\
        '},[]]]]);
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <div class="noscript"><p>Sorry, JavaScript must be enabled.<br/>Change your browser options, then <a href="">try again</a>.</p></div>
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Included the link

Comment: Provide us that link.

Comment: @Sraw check the edit, and top of the page.